# SQL Trigger with loop from another table

Tags: sql, for-loop, while-loop, triggers, database-cursor

I've got 2 tables :

Table A

```
create table A
(id int identity(1,1)
,KeyWord1 nvarchar(50)
,KeyWord2 nvarchar(50)
,KeyWord3 nvarchar(50)
)
```

Table B

```
Create table B
(id int identity(1,1)
,Address nvarchar(150)
,Chk int
)
```

The table A contains the following values :

```
insert into A
values
(166, 'elyse', 'vry')
,(243, 'virginia', 'beach')
,(134, 'aris', 'adium')
```

The Table B contains the following values :

```
insert into B
values
('35 stadium street, 134 Paris', null)
,('243, Stadiumù road from Paris', null)
```

My goal is to set the column B.chk with the number of occurence from table A when a new row is created on table B.

For example :

```
insert into B
values
('166, road to Champs elysee - 14215 Cdx Evry', null)
```

The trigger on table B should set B.Chk at 1 cause the following query is matching with the table A

```
select count(*) from inserted
where b.Address like '%166%'
and b.Address like '%elyse%'
and b.Address like '%vry%'
```

For this i should create a trigger on Table B but don't know how to "loop" on the other table.
Should i user for, while or a cursor ?

Comment: What do you mean by loop and what are you going to loop over? SQL is declarative language, it accepts `select` statements with `where` condition and returns the answer without loops

Comment: Sample data, with examples of what should match and not match would really help.

Comment: Triggers are almost always a bad idea. Do you really need this field to be immediately populated? Or are you just trying to run a report to identify this?

Comment: No *looping* is required, although doing a non-sargable lookup in a trigger is not going to be great for its performance, if you don't *need* the column updated instantly you should schedule this process periodically. [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) your specific database platform.

Comment: Yes i need a trigger cause the value of the column will start a workflow from  another application.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You was right, i don't need a loop but chk column need to be set immediately after insert.

Here is my trigger :

```
 Create trigger TR_Update_B
 ON dbo.B
 AFTER insert
 AS
 BEGIN

 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 DECLARE @docNo int
 DECLARE @Result int

 SELECT @DocNo=id FROM inserted;

 SET @Result= (select count(*) from b
 join a
 on b.Address like '%'+a.KeyWord1+'%' 
 and b.Address like '%'+a.KeyWord2+'%' 
 and b.Address like '%'+a.KeyWord3+'%' 
 where b.id=@DocNo)

 Update b set Chk = @Result where id=@DocNo

 END
```

Comment: From this I can see what you want to do. You have, unfortunately, created a trigger with a classic and common flaw, in that your trigger assumes no more than a single row will ever be inserted. What would be the value of `@docNo` if 2 rows are inserted? The trigger fires *once* per statement, so if you insert 10 rows it will run once and `@docNo` will be one (random) `Id`.

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger needs to be constructed to treat the `inserted` virtual table as a *set*, just like in any other SQL statement.

You do not and should not need or use local variables to hold values in a trigger since the trigger operates on the *set of affected rows*.

Please try the following instead:

```
create or alter trigger TR_Update_B
on dbo.B
after insert
as
set nocount on;

with t as (
    select i.id, Count(*) qty
    from inserted i 
    join a on
            i.Address like '%' + a.KeyWord1 + '%' 
        and i.Address like '%' + a.KeyWord2 + '%' 
        and i.Address like '%' + a.KeyWord3 + '%' 
    group by i.id
)
update b set
b.chk=t.qty
from t
join b on b.id=t.id;
```